# How to convert an integer array into an ip address in c++?

Tags: c++

I have an array ipAddress[4] with 4 integer values e.g. 127,0,0,1 and I need to convert it to a string "127.0.0.1".

How can I do this?

Edit: Just to clarify, I need this at a later point to compare with an input from a function. I do not want to print this out on the screen.

Comment: why are you looking for some complex solution instead of a simple `<<`?

Comment: I need it at a later point to compare with an input I am receiving from a function. I don't want to print it.

Comment: strings have `+` as well

Comment: @Anantmurti well you got an `std::string` that contains the ip address. Isn't that what you wanted ?

Comment: why don't just compare as a simple IP or 32-bit int type? what if the user inputs `127.00.00.00.1`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way is:

```
char buf[16];
snprintf( buf, sizeof buf, "%d.%d.%d.%d",
    ipAddress[0], ipAddress[1], ipAddress[2], ipAddress[3] );
```

Personally I find this more elegant than 10-line solutions involving loops and multiple function calls, others will disagree!

Comment: Looks much more cleaner, then other solutions.Upvote!

Comment: note to editor: rolled back, OP did not say his array was `uint8_t`

Comment: @M.M True, but IPv4 address octets are unsigned 8-bit values by design, so anything else doesn't make sense

Comment: @EdKing there's some sense in using `int`.  `uint8_t` may be a character type which can introduce complications (e.g. it would break A.Sarid's and KostasRim's and GillBates' solutions)

Comment: I disagree based on context. I think my edit to your solution extends it in a sensible way, accounting for usage errors.

Comment: I liked this.  I made a variant which writes to a `std::ostringstream oss;` and then `oss.str()` is the droid I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `to_string()` method:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    int ipAddress[] = {127, 0, 0, 1};
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        s += to_string(ipAddress[i]);
        if(i != 4 - 1)
            s += '.';
    }
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

This will solve your problem

Comment: @M.M Well, in his example there was `.` in the end of `127.0.0.1.` which was misleading. Now it is fixed. But I still don't get why I got the -1!

Comment: probably got -1 while the answer was wrong and the person hasn't revisited. I wish they'd add an option to notify when something you voted on is edited

Comment: @M.M I just thought that he wanted `.` at the end of `127.0.0.1`. When someone downvote he could at least provide some explanation. Btw that option would be great!

Comment: I think the -1 was already there from when you didnt even have any `.` at all

Comment: @M.M that was my bad there and I was editing the answer. Still, no harm done!

Answer (score 0):

Just roll your own by looping through the array and adding the integers where needed:

```
constexpr int ipvals[] = {127, 0, 0, 1};
constexpr size_t size_vals = sizeof(ipvals) / sizeof(*ipvals);
std::ostringstream ss;
for(int i = 0; i < size_vals; ++i)
{
    ss << ipvals[i];
    if(i != size_vals - 1)
      ss << '.';
}
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/OdgT80)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert it using [`inet_ntoa()`](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/inet_ntoaman.html) as you mentioned you can do:

```
int main() {
    struct in_addr addr;
    char* some_addr;
    int ipAddress[] = {127,0,0,1};

    addr.s_addr = (ipAddress[3] << 24) | (ipAddress[2] << 16) | (ipAddress[1] << 8) | ipAddress[0];
    some_addr = inet_ntoa(addr);
    printf("%s\n", some_addr);

    return 0;
}
```

[Test](http://ideone.com/41Cemh)

**EDIT:** The main post has been edited, but the original stated he tried using the `inet_ntoa()` method for this.

Answer (score 0):

Edit of M.M's answer to make a C/C++ function specific for IPv4 addresses; forcing use of valid address input and buffer length for output:

```
bool ipv4_addr_to_str(uint8_t (*ipv4_addr)[4], char (*str)[16])
{
    bool success = false;
    if (ipv4_addr != NULL && str != NULL)
    {
        memset(*str, 0, 16);
        snprintf(*str, sizeof(*str), "%d.%d.%d.%d", 
                (*ipv4_addr)[0], (*ipv4_addr)[1], (*ipv4_addr)[2], (*ipv4_addr)[3]);
        success = true;
    }
    return success;
}
```